# How to convert *sql.Rows to typed JSON in Golang

Tags: sql, json, go, web-applications, struct

Essentially, I am trying to run a query on a MySQL database, get the data made converted into JSON and sent back to the client. I have tried several methods and all of the "easy" ones result in sending back all of the JSON as a string. I need this to be send back as a key (`string`) with `[]float64` value. This way I have an array of data associated with a key. Also, this needs to have a type. The best method I've found so far to accomplish this was to build put all of the data into a struct, encode it and send that back to the `ResponseWriter`.

I have seen several questions on making JSON from a database but I haven't found anything utilizing the struct method. I wrote the below code into a single function to illustrate my question. This is VERY limited in that it will only handle two fields and it MUST be a `float64`.

Therefore, my question is: How do I create this JSON from a query response that has the correct type before sending this back to the client and is there a way to do this dynamically (ie, can accept a variable number of columns and unknown types)?:

```
{ "Values":[12.54, 76.98, 34.90], "Dates": ["2017-02-03", "2017-02-04:, "2017-02-05"]}
```

```
    type DbDao struct{
      db *sql.DB
    }

    type JSONData struct {
      Values []float64
      Dates []string
    }


    func (d *DbDao) SendJSON(sqlString string, w http.ResponseWriter) (error) {

      stmt, err := d.db.Prepare(sqlString)
      if err != nil {
        return err
      }
      defer stmt.Close()

      rows, err := stmt.Query()
      if err != nil {
        return err
      }
      defer rows.Close()

      values := make([]interface{}, 2)
      scanArgs := make([]interface{}, 2)
      for i := range values {
        scanArgs[i] = &values[i]
      }

      for rows.Next() {
        err := rows.Scan(scanArgs...)
        if err != nil {
          return err
        }

        var tempDate string 
        var tempValue float64
        var myjson JSONData

        d, dok := values[0].([]byte)
        v, vok := values[1].(float64)

        if dok {
          tempDate = string(d)
          if err != nil {
            return err
          }
          myjson.Dates = append(myjson.Dates, tempDate)
        }

        if vok {      
          tempValue = v 
          myjson.Values = append(myjson.Values, tempValue)
          fmt.Println(v)
          fmt.Println(tempValue)

        }    

        err = json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(&myjson)
        if err != nil {
          return err
        }
      }

      return nil 
    }
```

Comment: To confirm; you want to build the struct from the query response, automatically turn it into JSON and return it to the client?

Comment: Yes. I was thinking I could use the rows.ColumnTypes and rows.Columns but didn't know how to create this into a struct dynamically that would then also do the type checking for type assertion.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a much better way to do it (Tested with Postgres). No reflect/reflection needed:

```
    columnTypes, err := rows.ColumnTypes()

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    count := len(columnTypes)
    finalRows := []interface{}{};

    for rows.Next() {

        scanArgs := make([]interface{}, count)

        for i, v := range columnTypes {

            switch v.DatabaseTypeName() {
            case "VARCHAR", "TEXT", "UUID", "TIMESTAMP":
                scanArgs[i] = new(sql.NullString)
                break;
            case "BOOL":
                scanArgs[i] = new(sql.NullBool)
                break;
            case "INT4":
                scanArgs[i] = new(sql.NullInt64)
                break;
            default:
                scanArgs[i] = new(sql.NullString)
            }
        }

        err := rows.Scan(scanArgs...)

        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        masterData := map[string]interface{}{}

        for i, v := range columnTypes {

            if z, ok := (scanArgs[i]).(*sql.NullBool); ok  {
                masterData[v.Name()] = z.Bool
                continue;
            }

            if z, ok := (scanArgs[i]).(*sql.NullString); ok  {
                masterData[v.Name()] = z.String
                continue;
            }

            if z, ok := (scanArgs[i]).(*sql.NullInt64); ok  {
                masterData[v.Name()] = z.Int64
                continue;
            }

            if z, ok := (scanArgs[i]).(*sql.NullFloat64); ok  {
                masterData[v.Name()] = z.Float64
                continue;
            }

            if z, ok := (scanArgs[i]).(*sql.NullInt32); ok  {
                masterData[v.Name()] = z.Int32
                continue;
            }

            masterData[v.Name()] = scanArgs[i]
        }

        finalRows = append(finalRows, masterData)
    }


    z, err := json.Marshal(finalRows)
```

Comment: I agree. Thanks for the post. In 2017 the ColumnTypes() wasn't in the golang library so this makes it much cleaner.

Comment: for sure, this isn't 100% complete it terms of all the case statements since there are lot more column types not covered, but it's 80% of the way there.

Comment: This solution is much better almost perfect

Comment: I had to make one change to this. The `TEXT` data type is used at my company to store raw json objects. To preserve their structure, I mark `TEXT` columns as `json.RawMessage` instead of `sql.NullString`

Answer (score 15):

This is the best implementation that I was able to come up with that would make it dynamic. It is also significantly shorter than my original. As I've seen this type of question quite a bit, I hope this helps others. I am open to other answers that have a better implementation of this:

```
func (d *DbDao) makeStructJSON(queryText string, w http.ResponseWriter) error {

    // returns rows *sql.Rows
    rows, err := d.db.Query(queryText)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    columns, err := rows.Columns()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    count := len(columns)
    values := make([]interface{}, count)
    scanArgs := make([]interface{}, count)
    for i := range values {
        scanArgs[i] = &values[i]
    }

    masterData := make(map[string][]interface{})

    for rows.Next() {
        err := rows.Scan(scanArgs...)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        for i, v := range values {

            x := v.([]byte)

            //NOTE: FROM THE GO BLOG: JSON and GO - 25 Jan 2011:
            // The json package uses map[string]interface{} and []interface{} values to store arbitrary JSON objects and arrays; it will happily unmarshal any valid JSON blob into a plain interface{} value. The default concrete Go types are:
            //
            // bool for JSON booleans,
            // float64 for JSON numbers,
            // string for JSON strings, and
            // nil for JSON null.

            if nx, ok := strconv.ParseFloat(string(x), 64); ok == nil {
                masterData[columns[i]] = append(masterData[columns[i]], nx)
            } else if b, ok := strconv.ParseBool(string(x)); ok == nil {
                masterData[columns[i]] = append(masterData[columns[i]], b)
            } else if "string" == fmt.Sprintf("%T", string(x)) {
                masterData[columns[i]] = append(masterData[columns[i]], string(x))
            } else {
                fmt.Printf("Failed on if for type %T of %v\n", x, x)
            }

        }
    }

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    err = json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(masterData)

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return err
}
```

Comment: This isn't really a good solution because it converts everything to a string, and then opportunistically converts things back to JSON types. It will trick you into thinking everything works but as soon as a user puts in their name as "true" or their house name as "32" it will break.

Comment: this seems like a safer solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60386531/12849275

Answer (score 10):

Here is a better solution, using reflection. It handles types correctly (e.g. a string value of `true` won't erroneously be turned into a bool and so on.

It also handles possibly-null types (only tested with MySQL - you will probably need to modify it for other drivers).

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"

    "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

// Additional scan types returned by the MySQL driver. I haven't looked at
// what PostgreSQL does.

type jsonNullInt64 struct {
    sql.NullInt64
}

func (v jsonNullInt64) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    if !v.Valid {
        return json.Marshal(nil)
    }
    return json.Marshal(v.Int64)
}

type jsonNullFloat64 struct {
    sql.NullFloat64
}

func (v jsonNullFloat64) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    if !v.Valid {
        return json.Marshal(nil)
    }
    return json.Marshal(v.Float64)
}

type jsonNullTime struct {
    mysql.NullTime
}

func (v jsonNullTime) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    if !v.Valid {
        return json.Marshal(nil)
    }
    return json.Marshal(v.Time)
}

var jsonNullInt64Type = reflect.TypeOf(jsonNullInt64{})
var jsonNullFloat64Type = reflect.TypeOf(jsonNullFloat64{})
var jsonNullTimeType = reflect.TypeOf(jsonNullTime{})
var nullInt64Type = reflect.TypeOf(sql.NullInt64{})
var nullFloat64Type = reflect.TypeOf(sql.NullFloat64{})
var nullTimeType = reflect.TypeOf(mysql.NullTime{})

// SQLToJSON takes an SQL result and converts it to a nice JSON form. It also
// handles possibly-null values nicely. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52572145/265521
func SQLToJSON(rows *sql.Rows) ([]byte, error) {
    columns, err := rows.Columns()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("Column error: %v", err)
    }

    tt, err := rows.ColumnTypes()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("Column type error: %v", err)
    }

    types := make([]reflect.Type, len(tt))
    for i, tp := range tt {
        st := tp.ScanType()
        if st == nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("Scantype is null for column: %v", err)
        }
        switch st {
        case nullInt64Type:
            types[i] = jsonNullInt64Type
        case nullFloat64Type:
            types[i] = jsonNullFloat64Type
        case nullTimeType:
            types[i] = jsonNullTimeType
        default:
            types[i] = st
        }
    }

    values := make([]interface{}, len(tt))
    data := make(map[string][]interface{})

    for rows.Next() {
        for i := range values {
            values[i] = reflect.New(types[i]).Interface()
        }
        err = rows.Scan(values...)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("Failed to scan values: %v", err)
        }
        for i, v := range values {
            data[columns[i]] = append(data[columns[i]], v)
        }
    }

    return json.Marshal(data)
}
```

Comment: what about this way? https://stackoverflow.com/a/60386531/12849275

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option you have is to use [json](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) library from golang

```
import "encoding/json"

type JSONData struct {
  Values []float64 `json:"Values"`
  Dates []string `json:"Dates"`
}
```

I don't think there is a good way to do this dynamically, since golang has no way of matching up the database column name and the output'd json Also as a side note I usually write the db querying code by sending the type directly to the db library

```
var tempDate string 
var tempValue float64
err := rows.Scan(&tempDate, &tempValue)
if err != nil {
       return err
}
```

If you really want to do this automatically you can look into golang [code generation](https://blog.golang.org/generate).

Comment: I appreciate your input. This doesn't really solve my problem but I will check into the link you gave on code generation.